# Suds-jurko http error

Tags: python-3.x, soap

I use python3 and sud-jurko
This my code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
wsdl_url = 'http://192.168.1.5/Base/ws/ws1.1cws'
t = HttpAuthenticated(username='login', password='pass')
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, transport=t)
print (client)
```

When run i get error:

```
(testik) C:\Users\Admin\testik>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 67
, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 13
2, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    client = Client(url=wsdl_url, transport=t)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 115, in __
init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 150, in op
en
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 136, in __in
it__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 74, in ope
n
    d = self.download(url)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 92, in dow
nload
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 23
5, in open
    return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\testik\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 69
, in open
    raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

(testik) C:\Users\Admin\testik>
```

What i am doing wrong. Please help me.
.-----------------------
. ------------------
.------------------
.---------------------
.------------------